# Kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I have been able to successfully setup kubernetes on my Centos 7 server.
On trying to get the dashboard working after following the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/), running 'kubectl proxy' it 
attempts to run using 127.0.0.1:9001 and not my server ip. Do this mean I cannot access kubernetes dashboard outside the server? 
I need help on getting the dashboard running using my public ip

Comment: Dashboard is accessible only on local. You should open the port on your server to point to the 9001 and you should be able to access it using public IP

Comment: Although thinking security why would you want the dashboard to be visible using public IP? There are other ways to monitor and deploy.

Comment: @AniAggarwal what other ways do you recommend to monitor and deploy?

Comment: kubectl through the command line

Comment: Or if you are on GKE the use their gcloud util

Answer (score 1):

You can specify on which address you want to run `kubectl proxy`, i.e.

```
kubectl proxy --address <EXTERNAL-IP> -p 9001
Starting to serve on 100.105.***.***:9001
```

You can also use port forwarding to access the dashboard.

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/dashboard 8888:80
```

This will listen port 8888 on all addresses and route traffic directly to your pod.

For instance:

```
rsha:~$ kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 deploy/webserver 8888:80
Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:8888 -> 80
```

In another terminal running

```
rsha:~$ curl 100.105.***.***:8888
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you would like to access the dashboard from your laptop. What you should do is create an admin account called k8s-admin:

```
$ kubectl --namespace kube-system create serviceaccount k8s-admin
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding k8s-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:k8s-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin
```

Then setup kubectl on your laptop, e.g. for macOS it looks like this (see [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/)):

```
$ brew install kubernetes-cli
```

Setup a proxy to your workstation. Create a `~/.kube` directory on your laptop and then scp the `~/.kube/config` file from the k8s (Kubernetes) master to your `~/.kube` directory.

Then get the authentication token you need to connect to the dashboard:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep k8s-admin | awk '{print $1}')
```

Now start the proxy:

```
$ kubectl proxy
```

Now open the dashboard by going to:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

You should see the `Token` option and then copy-paste the token from the prior step and Sign-In.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@salqadri/build-your-own-multi-node-kubernetes-cluster-with-monitoring-346a7e2ef6e2).