# Other pc can't visit k8s dashboard

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, settings, docker-for-mac

1. My mac can visit k8s dashboard, but other pc can't.  What's the reason ?

   - @kubernetes/UI       @kubernetes/dashboard
   - I have tried with the latest version of my channel (Stable or Edge)
   - macOS Version: 10.14
   - Docker for Mac: version: 19.03.1
   - k8s version : 1.14.3
   - eneble k8s on docker for mac setting
   - apply k8s dashboard.yaml
   - my mac ip is : 192.168.0.200
2. `kubectl get service --all-namaspaces`

> NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE
>   CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    default  ......... 
>   kubernetes            .........       ClusterIP    .........
>   10.96.0.1     .........            443/TCP                   kube-system     ..........       kubernetes-dashboard    .........
>   NodePort      .........  10.104.38.247     .........
>   443:31317/TCP

3. `kubectl cluster-info`

> Kubernetes master is running at
>   https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443 KubeDNS is running at
>   https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

4. I can visit dashboard with below url  on  my pc.

> kubernetes.docker.internal:31317 localhost:31317
>   127.0.0.1:31317
>   192.168.0.200:31317

And I have stopped firewall.

5. One Lan,  other pc can't visit 192.168.0.200:31317

And I don't know why.
help me , thanks.
Do you need other info?

Actually, I ask same question on github, and they suggest me to ask it on stackoverflow.
And this is my first time ask question on stackoverflow, and if I do something wrong, please tell me.

6. I excepted that other pc including windows and mac on the same LAN can visit my mac's k8s dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run kubectl proxy locally for accessing the dashboard outside the kubernetes cluster. You need to scp admin.conf file (file on your kubernetes master at `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`) to the machine from which you want to access the dashboard and pass it to kubectl command. Please, refer to following posts:

- [How to access/expose kubernetes-dashboard service outside of a cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864385/how-to-access-expose-kubernetes-dashboard-service-outside-of-a-cluster)
- [Kubernetes dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041415/kubernetes-dashboar)

To access the Dashboard navigate your browser to `https://<server_IP>:31317`

Comment: Oh, I have read these posts. Thank you very much much much .
I have to install kubectl  Or update https 。 And then I will try kubectl .